# Replicate Log10 Scaling with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to recreate a plot that has the y-axis styled as so:

[image]

But can't seem to figure out how to get the axis breaks and labels lined up how I want them. I am currently doing this in my code:

```py
# plot lines
for key, group in grouped:
    plt.plot(group.x * 950, np.log10(group.y), label=key)

# plot points
exp_group = exp_data.groupby('Experiment')
for key, group in exp_group:
    plt.plot(group.x, np.log10(group.y), label=key, marker='o')

plt.yticks(np.arange(-3, 3), label=10.0**np.arange(-3,3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you would be better off leaving your data scaled normally (i.e. not use `np.log10()`) and instead plot on semi-log axes. See https://matplotlib.org/gallery/scales/log_demo.html?highlight=semilogy

Comment: I'm tempted to say that in order to get the ticks right (look at the top and right), you might have to use a secondary axis https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-secondary-axis-py

Comment: @David I'm not so concerned about the ticks on all sides or really in general, just having the y-axis be labeled `[.1, 1, 10, 100]` would be enough to warrant an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use [`plt.yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.exp(x) - x**3 + x**2 - x**(1/2)

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(x, y)
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
print(locs)
print(labels)
lst_10 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
plt.yticks(lst_10, lst_10)
plt.title('Different label on y-axis')

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(x, y)
plt.title('Default label')
plt.show()
```

The function `plt.yticks` takes two arguments, the locations and the labels. I want the labels in the locations 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000; I want the label (in location 1) to have a label `1`, the label (in localtion 10) to have a label `10`, and so on. I have also used `plt.semilogy` to get that semi-log axis.